# restricted cubic splines (Cox adjusted)

Tags: cox-model, splines

I'm trying to make restricted cubic splines where "Age" in x axis and "Hazard ratio" in y axis: similar figure to the Fig 4 in the following paper.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5807010/

I can draw unadjusted restricted cubic splines using rcspline.plot in r Hmisc library. The script I used is as follows:rcspline.plot(x = df$Age, y = Surv(df$OAS, df$Death), event = df$Death)
*OAS=overall survival
However, I want to draw restricted cubic splines curve which is adjusted by several patient factors such as sex, tumor histologic grade, etc.
Please give me information on what kind of script I should use.- I want to set knots at age of 30, 50, 70 years.
It would be helpful if you could give me script where I should only copy and paste.